# Execute code once Sinatra server is running

Tags: ruby, sinatra

I have a Sinatra Application enclosed in `Sinatra::Base` and I'd like to run some code once the server has started, how should I go about doing this?

Here's an example:

```
require 'sinatra'
require 'launchy'

class MyServer < Sinatra::Base
  get '/' do
    "My server"
  end

  # This is the bit I'm not sure how to do
  after_server_running do
    # Launches a browser with this webapp in it upon server start
    Launchy.open("http://#{settings.host}:#{settings.port}/")
  end
end
```

Any ideas?

Comment: You might need to be more specific to get some help.

Comment: You're proabbly right - I thought it was self-explanatory! lets see how these modifications help

Comment: This is not what you asked, but you should be require'ing `sinatra/base`, not `sinatra`. From http://www.sinatrarb.com/intro.html#Sinatra::Base%20-%20Middleware,%20Libraries,%20and%20Modular%20Apps: "Your file should require sinatra/base instead of sinatra; otherwise, all of Sinatra’s DSL methods are imported into the main namespace."

Answer (score 5):

Using the configure block is not the correct way to do this. Whenever you load the file the commands will be run.

Try extending `run!`

```
require 'sinatra'
require 'launchy'

class MyServer < Sinatra::Base

  def self.run!
    Launchy.open("http://#{settings.host}:#{settings.port}/")
    super
  end

  get '/' do
    "My server"
  end
end
```

Comment: If you want your code to run _after_ startup you might want to have the call to `super` first in the method.

Comment: Also, this is better than using `configure` blocks your getting code to run after server start, but will only work for the build in server – it won’t work if you use e.g. `rackup` or `thin start`.

Comment: @matt actually if you call Launchy after super it will never be reached, I tried it out. settings.host wasn't working as well, I replaced it to localhost since I'm using it only locally.

Comment: good point. It looks like there isn’t a reliable way to run code after the server starts, at least from within Sinatra itself.

Answer (score 2):

This is how I do it; basically running either sinatra or the other code in a separate thread:

```
require 'sinatra/base'

Thread.new { 
  sleep(1) until MyApp.settings.running?
  p "this code executes after Sinatra server is started"
}
class MyApp < Sinatra::Application
  # ... app code here ...

  # start the server if ruby file executed directly
  run! if app_file == $0
end
```

Answer (score 2):

If you're using Rack (which you probably are) I just found out there's a function you can call in `config.ru` (it's technically an instance method of `Rack::Builder`) that lets you run a block of code after the server has been started. It's called [`warmup`](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/rack/rack/Rack%2FBuilder%3Awarmup), and here's the documented usage example:

```
warmup do |app|
  client = Rack::MockRequest.new(app)
  client.get('/')
end

use SomeMiddleware
run MyApp
```

Comment: This works really well with the Launchy.open() call in the original question. Although it is probably a good idea to check for ENV['RACK_ENV'] == "development" first as you probably don't want this run in production.

Answer (score -1):

The only valid answer in stackoverflow to this question (which is asked 3-4 times) is given by [levinalex](https://stackoverflow.com/users/55534/levinalex) on [Start and call Ruby HTTP server in the same script](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16543644/3970469), and I quote:

> [`run!` in current Sinatra versions](http://rubydoc.info/gems/sinatra/Sinatra/Base#run%21-class_method) takes a block that is called when the app is started.
>
> Using that callback you can do this:
>
> ```
> require 'thread'
>
> def sinatra_run_wait(app, opts)
>   queue = Queue.new
>   thread = Thread.new do
>     Thread.abort_on_exception = true
>     app.run!(opts) do |server|
>       queue.push("started")
>     end
>   end
>   queue.pop # blocks until the run! callback runs
> end
>
> sinatra_run_wait(TestApp, :port => 3000, :server => 'webrick')
> ```
>
> This seems to be reliable for WEBrick, but when using Thin the callback is still sometimes called a little bit before the server accepts connections.

Comment: I'm love to understand why you'd say it's the only valid answer when you also say it only works reliably for webrick (which really isn't meant to be used outside dev and even then is of limited utility).  Could you expand on why the other answers don't work?

Comment: Every other solution I see is hacky. This is the only solution that relies on what (little) guarantees the framework in use makes. Sinatra will pass the `server` object when it "starts", so then we know the application is started. The issue that arises from webservers will be present with any other hacky solution (including the ones presented above).