# How to detect, that server is started in Sinatra/Thin

Tags: ruby, sinatra, thin

I have code like:

```
Thread.new do
  builder = Rack::Builder.new do
    map('/'){ run Server }
  end
  Rack::Handler::Thin.run builder, :Port => 8585
end
#how do i detect, that Server is running here (or wait for it)
```

How can i detect, that Server is running and able to receive requests?

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Execute code once Sinatra server is running](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2589356/execute-code-once-sinatra-server-is-running)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `defined?` method to check for this, e.g.

```
if defined? Rack::Handler::Thin
   # We're running under Thin. Do stuff.
else
   # nope :(
end
```

Answer (score 0):

use `curl` in terminal. `curl http://yourapp.com:8585/` If this returns the page at `'/'`, then the server is up.

Comment: yeah, i used that solution, but does not seem to be elegant